How to serve the same cached index.html from CloudFront for all routes of a SPA
I have a standard architecture for a single page app:

served through CloudFront
origin is an S3 bucket

Works perfectly when the SPA is requested through its root domain https://example.com. The response time is 50ms.
However, when any route is added to the url like https://example.com/route1, CloudFront experiences a cache miss, and tries to find that route at the origin. Origin responds with 404, so CloudFront serves default response index.html.
Time to first byte takes from 0.5, up to 1 second.
How to have CloudFront serve a single common index.html for any of the routes different from the root?
https://app.clickup.com has somehow pulled this off. If you add any arbitrary route, the response is a consistent 50ms Cache Hit from CloudFront.
I also tried with viewer-request CloudFront function: the timings are 150-200ms. Still far from what clickup has achieved.
function handler(event) {
  var request = event.request;
  var uri = request.uri;
  
  if (!uri.includes('.': ) { //maintain default behavior for static js, css, or image assets
      request.uri = '/index.html';
  }
  
  return request;
}

This is how I'm measuring:
curl -w "\nDNS Lookup: %{time_namelookup}s\nTCP Connect: %{time_connect}s\nTLS Handshake: %{time_appconnect}s\nFirst Byte: %{time_starttransfer}s\nTotal Time: %{time_total}s\n" -o /dev/null -s https://app.clickup.com/bla


I think the site you're talking about is using SSR to return pre-rendered content, which is remarkably snappy.
In your case, you might be better off moving your cloudfront function to an origin-request lambda@edge. This way it won't be executed for every request and the content might be cached a little better.

The reason I don't think that's the case is because any arbitrary sub-route request to that site returns in a consistent 50ms timeframe. Always cache hit.
